# Library/API/program for converting Flash code into html5 code

Tags: flash, html

What library/API or even a program for converting flash code into html 5 code automatically do you recommend me?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that [Gordon](http://github.com/tobeytailor/gordon) is a flash runtime written in JS, it seems like it would be possible to create a version that compiles flash to JS based on the same code. Not trivial, but doable, and a lot of the hard work is already done.

A couple of notes - beware of the [browser compatibility issues](http://wiki.github.com/tobeytailor/gordon/browser-support-table/) and [swf tag support](http://wiki.github.com/tobeytailor/gordon/swf-tag-support-table) in Gordon currently, and target accordingly.

**Edit** *(thanks naikus!):* Looks like (as was inevitable) work has already started on a flash to JS compiler called [Smokescreen](http://smokescreen.us/). It is supposed to be [open-source](http://smokescreen.us/2010/05/01/free-as-in-beer-and-speech/), but for now I only see [demos](http://smokescreen.us/demo/), so we'll still to wait for the complete deal (though I suppose you could perhaps dig around their js code for tips/etc in the meantime).

Comment: 2013: Smokescreen.us is dead? Website looks like it is not finished.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, you should also look into Haxe.

This Hook Labs blog post is worth a read:

http://labs.byhook.com/2010/04/09/i-brought-my-haxe/

Answer (score 1):

It’s not going to happen. Flash is the product of one company. HTML5 (and associated bits, like CSS) are standards developed by lots of companies working, at various degrees of togetherness, over decades.

You’ll never be able to port automatically from one to the other, at least not with satisfactory results. That’s my bet, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Oh cruel heavens, thou mockest me! I wish this were available!

Some news:

http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/04/adobe-flash-iphone/

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Adobe-Flash-CS5-Can-Export-to-HTML5-Canvas-139597.shtml

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2361949,00.asp

http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

You can embed flash in html5, but if you're looking for a converter to turn flash/flex into interactive javascript/html5, then get in line with the rest of us. You're in good company. :-)

Comment: Given that http://github.com/tobeytailor/gordon is a flash runtime written in JS, it seems like it would be possible to create a version that compiles flash to JS based on the same code. Not trivial, but doable, and a lot of the hard work is already done.

Comment: @jball: cool, didn't hear about that. you should post that as your own answer :-)

Comment: I guess it's worthy of being an answer; posted.